# SSIS Script Task - Reading RecordSet object in a loop is failing

Tags: ssis

I've collected a dataset and assigned it to an object variable using the RecordSet destination.

Based off of the number of records in the dataset, I need to loop through the dataset and spit out records to a file. For example, if there were 5000 records in the original dataset, I need to loop through it 5 times to create a file containing 1000 records, called MyFile_1.txt, MyFile_2.txt, etc.

In my script component task in the dataflow, I'm populating the output buffer with the columns from the RecordSet. In doing this, I create a new OleDbAdapter and DataTable, then fill them with the object variable.

This works great the first time. However, the second time, the DataAdapter.Fill(DataTable, ObjectVariable) method executes without error, but the DataTable has no rows in it. While debugging, I can drill down to see that the Object variable still has records in it.

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Questions about code that supply no actual code are fairly challenging to debug. That said, I *believe* that by calling the `Fill` method you are consuming the entire record set object. The marker is now at the end of the recordset. You would either need to reset the marker to the last "used" point or consume only the rows you need per pass through the data flow.

Comment: Sorry, I'm executing this in a very basic manner from the script task:

OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter();
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
da.Fill(dt, Variables.MyRecordSet);

The first pass contains records, the second time it fires, no records. How do I reset the marker to the last used point?

Comment: I don't know, which is why I posted as a comment and not answer. My approach would be to not use the `Fill` method and instead consume it row by row until I've hit my limit

Comment: Why are you doing a second pass on the recordset? Also, what version of SSIS are you using?

Comment: Do you actually need to use a script recordset? Can you use `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Table` to get the recordset count first, then use something like `ROWNUMBER` to get a record number and split it accordingly. What is the source for this data?

Answer (score 2):

Here's a Script Task that works. It requires a reference to Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects 2.x

```
public void Main()
        {

            OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter();
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();

            ADODB.Stream stm = new  ADODB.Stream();
            ADODB.Recordset rs = ((ADODB.Recordset)Dts.Variables["User::Variable"].Value).Clone();
            ADODB.Recordset rsCopy = new ADODB.Recordset();

            rs.Save(stm);
            rsCopy.Open(stm);
            da.Fill(dt, rs);
            dt.Clear();
            da.Fill(dt, rsCopy);
            Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
        }
```

You can pull the data from the stream into a new recordset as many times as you need.