# SSIS - Object variable converted to DataTable becomes empty

Tags: c#, ssis, etl

I'm trying to create an object variable that will hold a collection from an ***Execute SQL Task***. This collection will be used in multiple ***Script Task*** throughout the ETL package.

The problem is, after the first `Fill` of the first ***Script Task***, the object variable becomes empty. Here's a code on how I used the variable to a DataTable:

```
try
            {
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();

                OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter();

                da.Fill(dt, Dts.Variables["reportMetrics"].Value);

                Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
            }
            catch (Exception Ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(Ex.Message);
                Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Failure;
            }
```

Throughout the ETL package, ***Script Task*** components will have this piece of code. Since the variable becomes empty after the first `Fill`, I can't reuse the object variable.

I'm guessing that the Fill method has something to do with this.

Thanks!

Comment: Check out my answer to this question, it shows how to reuse the object variable with ADODB Streams http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25253319/ssis-script-task-reading-recordset-object-in-a-loop-is-failing/25256478#25256478

Answer (score 5):

It looks like your `Dts.Variables["reportMetrics"].Value` object holds `DataReader` object. This object allows forward-only read-only access to the data. You cannot fill DataTable twice using DataReader. To accomplish your task you need to create another script task that performs exactly what you described here: it reads the Reader to `DataTable` object and stores this `DataTable` object in another `Dts.Variable` with type Object.

`Dts.Variables["reportMetricsTable"].Value = dt`

After that all your subsequequent script tasks shall either create a copy of this table if they modify the data, or use it directly if they do not modify it.

`DataTable dtCopy = (Dts.Variables["reportMetricsTable"].Value as DataTable).Copy()`

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar situation. While I think you can do a SQL Task with a SELECT COUNT(*) query and assign the result to an SSIS variable, what I did was create an int SSIS variable called totalCount with an original value of 0. I expect the total count to be > 0 (otherwise, I won't have anything to iterate on) so I created an if statement within my Script Task. If the value is zero, I assume totalCount has not been initialized, so I use the same code you are using (with the Fill method). Otherwise (i.e, in further iterations), I skip that part and continue to use totalCount variable. Here's the block of code. Hope it helps:

```
if ((int)Dts.Variables["User::totalCount"].Value == 0)    // if the total count variable has not been initialized...
        {
            System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter da = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter();
            DataTable stagingTablesQryResult = new DataTable();
            da.Fill(stagingTablesQryResult, Dts.Variables["User::stagingTablesQryResultSet"].Value);    // to be used for logging how many files are we iterating. It may be more efficient to do a count(*) outside this script and save the total number of rows for the query but I made this as proof of concept for future developments.

            Dts.Variables["User::totalCount"].Value = stagingTablesQryResult.Rows.Count;
        }

Console.WriteLine("{0}. Looking for data file {0} of {1} using search string '{2}'.", counter, Dts.Variables["User::totalCount"].Value, fileNameSearchString);
```

Comment: Sorry, I believe that what you're looking for is to reuse the collection and not just the total number of elements. What if you create an SSIS variable of type Object and assign your DataTable variable to it within your Script Task ? I did something like that but it was an Array being assigned to an SSIS object variable but I would think the same logic applies. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Excellent

This has helped me around an issue in building myt ETL platform.

Essentially I execute a SQL task to build a dataset of tasks, there is some in line transformations and rules which pull the relevant tasks to the fore, which for obvious reasons I only want to execute the once per execution.

I then need to get the unique ProcessIDs from the data set (to use in a For Each Loop)

Within the FEL, I want to then fetch the relevant records from the original dataset to then push through a further FEL process.

I was facing the same "empty data set" for the 2nd execution against the dataset.

I thought I'd try to share my solution to assist others

You'll need to add the Namespaces

> using System.Data.OleDb;

into the Scripts

[Screen shot of solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/16ETa.png)

**Get dataset**

Execute SQL - Get your data and pass into a Variable Object

**Pull Ds**
[Declare the Variable Objects](https://i.stack.imgur.com/roqHJ.png)

```
 public void Main()
        {
            DataTable dt            = new DataTable();
            OleDbDataAdapter da     = new OleDbDataAdapter();
            //Read the original table
            da.Fill(dt, Dts.Variables["Tbl"].Value);
            //Push to a replica
            Dts.Variables["TblClone"].Value = dt;

            Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
        }
```

**Build Proc List**
This gets a list of ProcessIDs (and Names) by filtering on a Rank field in the dataset

[Declare the Variable Objects](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pWRWv.png)

```
public void Main()
        {  //Take a copy of the Cloned Dataset
            DataTable dtRead = (Dts.Variables["TblClone"].Value as DataTable).Copy();

            //Lock the output object variable
            Dts.VariableDispenser.LockForWrite("User::ProcTbl");

            //Create a data table to place the results into which we can write to the output object once finished
            DataTable dtWrite = new DataTable();

            //Create elements to the Datatable programtically
            //dtWrite.Clear();

            dtWrite.Columns.Add("ID", typeof(Int64));
            dtWrite.Columns.Add("Nm");

            //Start reading input rows
            foreach (DataRow dr in dtRead.Rows)
            {
                //If 1st col from Read object = ID var 
                if (Int64.Parse(dr[9].ToString()) == 1) //P_Rnk = 1 
                {
                    DataRow newDR = dtWrite.NewRow();

                        newDR[0] = Int64.Parse(dr[0].ToString());
                        newDR[1] = dr[4].ToString();

                    //Write the row
                    dtWrite.Rows.Add(newDR);
                }
            }

            //Write the dataset back to the object variable
            Dts.Variables["User::ProcTbl"].Value = dtWrite;
            Dts.Variables.Unlock();

            Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
        }
```

**Build TaskList from ProcList**

Cycle round ProcessID in a For Each Loop

[Build TL Collection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SiGqE.png)

..and map Vars

[Build TL Var Mappings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rq0HK.png)

Build TL Script
This will dynamically build the output for you (NB this works for me although havent extensively tested it, so if it doesnt work....have a fiddle with it).
You'll see I've commented out some Debug stuff

```
public void Main()
    {   
        //Clone the copied table
        DataTable dtRead = (Dts.Variables["TblClone"].Value as DataTable).Copy();

        //Read the var to filter the records by
        var ID = Int64.Parse(Dts.Variables["User::ProcID"].Value.ToString());

        //Lock the output object variable
        Dts.VariableDispenser.LockForWrite("User::SubTbl");

        //Debug Test the ProcID being passed
        //MessageBox.Show(@"Start ProcID =  " + ID.ToString());
        //MessageBox.Show(@"TblCols =  " + dtRead.Columns.Count);

        //Create a data table to place the results into which we can write to the output object once finished
        DataTable dtWrite   = new DataTable();

        //Create elements to the Datatable programtically
        //dtWrite.Clear();
        foreach (DataColumn dc in dtRead.Columns)
        {
            dtWrite.Columns.Add(dc.ColumnName, dc.DataType);
        }

        MessageBox.Show(@"TblRows =  " + dtRead.Rows.Count); 
        //Start reading input rows
        foreach (DataRow dr in dtRead.Rows)
        {
            //If 1st col from Read object = ID var 
            if (ID == Int64.Parse(dr[0].ToString()))
            {
                DataRow newDR = dtWrite.NewRow();

                //Dynamically create data for each column
                foreach (DataColumn dc in dtRead.Columns)
                {
                    newDR[dc.ColumnName] = dr[dc.ColumnName];
                }
                //Write the row
                dtWrite.Rows.Add(newDR);

                //Debug
                //MessageBox.Show(@"ProcID =  " + newDR[0].ToString() + @"TaskID =  " + newDR[1].ToString() + @"Name = " + newDR[4].ToString());
            }

        }
        //Write the dataset back to the object variable
        Dts.Variables["User::SubTbl"].Value = dtWrite;
        Dts.Variables.Unlock();

        Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
    }
```

**For Each Loop Container**

[FEL Cont Collection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zC9az.png)
N.B. Dont forget to map the items in the Variable Mappings

Now you can consume the records and do stuff with that data
I included the Msg Loop script as an easy data check...in reality this will go off and trigger other processes but just to aid you in data checks I though Id include it

**Msg Loop**

Msg Loop Script

```
public void Main()
        {
            // TODO: Add your code here
                MessageBox.Show("ID = " + Dts.Variables["User::ProcID"].Value + ", and val = " + Dts.Variables["User::TaskID"].Value, "Name = Result");

                Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;

        }
```

Hope that helps somebody solve their issue (Ive been tring to resolve this for a working day or so :/

Comment: please [edit] to make it look like if you were answering someone else. Don't thank others, just add a better/different answer to other answers?